# enable_if : case of templated method of a template base inherited several times

Tags: c++, templates, boost, enable-if

If I have a template base class with a template method :

```
template <typename T>
class S
{
public:

    template <typename U>
    void f(U p, typename enable_if<is_same<T, U> >::type*dummy = 0)
    {
        std::cout << p << std::endl;
    }
};
```

For the example, I simplify the method : it must "exists" only if T == U

If A is this class:

```
class A : public S<int> {};
```

Then I have what I want:

```
int i = 1;
A a;
a.f(i);
```

compiles, but

```
double d = 2.0;
a.f(d);
```

doesn't compile : error: no matching function for call to ‘A::f(double&)’
It is the expected behavior.

Now let's A inherit from `S<double>` also :

```
class A : public S<int>, public S<double> {};
```

Then the following code doesn't compile:

```
int i = 1;
A a;
a.f(i);
```

> ```
> error: request for member ‘f’ is ambiguous
>
> error: candidates are: template<class U> void S::f(U, typename
> boost::enable_if<boost::is_same<T, U>, void>::type*) [with U = U, T =
> double]
>
> error:                 template<class U> void S::f(U, typename
> boost::enable_if<boost::is_same<T, U>, void>::type*) [with U = U, T =
> int]
> ```

I expected there is no ambiguity : `f<int>` exists only for `S<int>`

In the compiler error, we can notice that T is known when this piece of code is compiled, but not U (U = U).

Any explanation or "workaround" ?

Comment: Any reason why `f` has to be templated?

Comment: To build on @Xeo's comment: since you want the parameter of `f` to be a `T`, why don't you just say so instead of relying on `enable_if`? `template <typename T> struct S { void f(T p) { std::cout << p << std::endl; } };`

Comment: (I just reread your question and saw that you said the method was simplified, so perhaps your actual code really needs `f` to be a method template.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
a.S<int>::f(i);
```

...or alternatively inject the function into `A`, e.g.

```
class A : public S<int>, public S<double> 
{
public:
  using S<int>::f;
  using S<double>::f;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You are right it only exists in S, but two times. Once for each type, int and double. So in your case you will need to specify exactly which function you want to call. The solution from Nim works just like that.

Comment: "*You are right it only exists in S, but two times.*" Actually the case is that there are two different `S`s.

Answer (score 0):

Others have given good workarounds, but I want to answer that other question you had

> I expected there is no ambiguity : `f<int>` exists only for `S<int>`.

You said `a.f(i)` so it first needs to look for name `f` in `A`. It finds two `f`s. In `S<int>` and `S<double>`. At name lookup time, it does not know yet that it later could have only selected `S<int>::f` as a winner because `S<double>::f` would be thrown away by SFINAE. The clear separation of name lookup and overload resolution and template argument deduction does not allow such intermingling.